# Flash like rendering on XNA

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, xna, rendering

Hey i was wondering if anyone knows if there's a Flash like render engine for XNA.
Am talking about child and parent relation rendering for 2d or maybe how this kind of rendering is called.

(before i try to implement my own)

Thanks :)

Comment: If you mean using a scene graph, then probably most rendering engines support that. Although it is not too hard to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scene graph seems to be the closest to flash like rendering with XNA, i will be implementing my own, i will link here if i make it open source :)